# How to train a machine learning model using reinforcement learning for Battleship to predict next best move?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, machine-learning

## Question

**How can I train a machine learning model to predict best next move using reinforcement learning for Battleship?**
(using reinforcement learning is the key of this question. I want it to learn the formulas for "best move from a statistical standpoint")

The best move is the one that minimized the number of turns until all ships are sunk.

I plan to use Tensorflow. From my understanding, this is how the model should look like for this problem:

```
# Each input neuron is a categorical variable:
# 0.00 < x <= 0.25: missed shot
# 0.25 < x <= 0.50: ship hit by shot
# 0.50 < x <= 0.75: sunk ship
# 0.75 < x <= 1.00: cell that has not been chosen/shot yet

tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5 * 5),  # input is a 5 x 5 board
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4),  # hidden layer, can be any number

    # output is a 5 x 5 board,
    # each with a value 0.00 <= x <= 1.00
    # low values are bad or invalid moves,
    # and high values are good moves
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5 * 5),
]
```

and in pseudocode for the whole algorithm:

```
# Creates a game board of size 5x5 with ships randomly placed in a valid configuration
game = setup_board(x=5, y=5)

until game.is_over():
    game.make_random_valid_move()

    # TODO: where and how should the reinforcement learning take place?
```

## Statistically best move

From a statistical standpoint the best:

- first move is anywhere not near edge
- move when there is a hit, but unsunk, ship is an adjacent cell

## Battleship rules (non-standard, simplified for StackExchange question)

- Grid/board is 5 units by 5 units
- Ships are randomly placed in horizontal or vertical orientation

  - Ships do not move across turns
- Ships must have at least one unit of padding between ships
- There are 1× 2-unit ship and 1× 3-unit ship

### Example configurations

- `·` denotes a missed shot
- `×` denotes ship hit by shot
- `█` denotes sunk ship
- denotes cell that has not been chosen/shot yet

#### Empty board

- Starting board for all games

```
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

#### First shot

- Sub-optimal first move

```
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

#### Optimal shot

- Since there are two hits, and ships cannot be adjacent, then then two shots must be hitting the same ship

  - the next shot should either be to the left or right of the existing shots

```
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░ × ░ × ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

##### Choose left

```
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░ × ░ × ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

##### Choose right

```
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░ █ ░ █ ░ █ ░ · ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

1. the `×` becomes `█` to denote that the ship is sunk
2. ships cannot be adjacent, so the adjacent cells are ruled out

#### Game over

```
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ █ ░ █ ░ · ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░ █ ░ █ ░ █ ░ · ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░ · ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
░   ░   ░   ░   ░   ░
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░
```

All ships have been sunk, so the game is over

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. This could be the basis of an interesting question, but it looks like you need a full tutorial on how to understand and implement reinforcement learning. That's not really feasible, it would be too much. Plus resources for that already exist. I suggest find a tutorial that does something similar to your game, and attempt to continue your project that way. Ask a more focused question when you hit a specific block that stops you following the example or tutorial

Comment: As a simple suggestion, I think you can solve this problem in various ways. Probably the classic *alpha-beta search* would be enough to solve small grids and should be way simpler to implement and debug than RL. Also, you can try a tabular RL algo like *policy iteration* to avoid the burden of deep RL. Another option, would be a model-based RL approach like using *monte carlo tree search* (MCTS).